# Solving an equation involving a determinant

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, special-functions

I have a matrix which doesn't include numerical values. There are four variables in it. It is defined by

```
M1 = ({
      {κ0  BesselJ[m, κ0 R],
       q BesselI[m, q*R], 
       q1 BesselK[m, q1*R],
       q2 BesselK[m, q2*R]},
      {((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 + N1*κ0^2)*BesselJ[(m + 1), κ0*R],
       ((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 - N1*q^2)*BesselI[(m + 1), q*R],
       -((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q1^2)*BesselK[(m + 1), q1*R],
       -((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q2^2)*BesselK[(m + 1), q2*R]},
      {κ0^2 BesselJ[(m + 1),
       κ0*R], -q^2 BesselI[m + 1, q*R],
       q1^2 BesselK[(m + 1),
       q1*R], q2^2 BesselK[(m + 1), q2*R]},
      {((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 + N1*κ0^2) κ0*BesselJ[m, κ0*R],
       ((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 - N1*q^2) q*BesselI[m, q*R],
       ((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q1^2) q1*BesselK[m, q1*R],
       ((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q2^2) q2*BesselK[m, q2*R]}
     });

Det[M1] = 0
```

I want to get the formula for E1 in terms of the other variables and constants. I used `Solve`, but it didn't work. Can anyone please help me? Really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You missed to write `==` and used `=` instead. What about

```
M1 = ({{\[Kappa]0 BesselJ[m, \[Kappa]0 R], q BesselI[m, q*R], 
     q1 BesselK[m, q1*R], 
     q2 BesselK[m, q2*R]}, {((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 + N1*\[Kappa]0^2)*
      BesselJ[(m + 1), \[Kappa]0*R], ((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 - N1*q^2)*
      BesselI[(m + 1), q*R], -((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q1^2)*
      BesselK[(m + 1), q1*R], -((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q2^2)*
      BesselK[(m + 1), 
       q2*R]}, {\[Kappa]0^2 BesselJ[(m + 1), \[Kappa]0*
        R], -q^2 BesselI[m + 1, q*R], q1^2 BesselK[(m + 1), q1*R], 
     q2^2 BesselK[(m + 1), 
       q2*R]}, {((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 + N1*\[Kappa]0^2) \[Kappa]0*
      BesselJ[m, \[Kappa]0*R], ((F1 /. L -> L1) - E1 - N1*q^2) q*
      BesselI[m, q*R], ((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q1^2) q1*
      BesselK[m, q1*R], ((F1 /. L -> L2) - E1 - N1*q2^2) q2*
      BesselK[m, q2*R]}});

Solve[Det[M1] == 0, E1]
```

Comment: I tried with that too. And end up with this error. "Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>"

Comment: I can give m=0,R=100. Even then it doesn't work.

Comment: What I actually want is to find E1 values when Determinant of matrix =0. Anyone, please help me.

Comment: @Thakshila It seems you have assigned values to some of the variables. Can you restart the Kernel or *Mathematica* and try again?

Comment: Thanks for helping me halirutan. But, it seems to be not working. Because it is still running. I got another idea to get a solution for my problem. I know E1 range. So, I will make tables for E1 and Det[M1]. Then how can get E1, when P1=0? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Thakshila Based on `F1 /. L -> L2`, it appears `F1` is intended to have some definition, but that shouldn't matter.  `Det[M1] // Factor` has `E1 - F1` as a simple factor and no other `E1` in the expression.

Comment: F1 depend on L2 which is a constant(a given value.) I tried with this code "Solve[Det[M1] == 0, E1, Reals]" It end up with the error."Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>"

Comment: Michael do you have any idea about making tables and get extract points.(As I told in my previous comment) I believe that using IF and Table, it should work. but I don't know how to write the code. Anyway thanks for trying to help me.